# How to remove year from datetime object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that is bound to a datatable from a db. One of the columns is a datetime field which I got to read in shortdate mode (mm/dd/yyyy). However, I was wondering if there was any easy to remove the year from the date time either in the cell or at the time of display.

```
    //Convert the "date" column to only appear in mm/dd format
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    String myS = row.Cells[2].Text;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[2].Text);

    row.Cells[2].Text = dt.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the standard `ToString` date formatter, with capital `MM` meaning "month month" and lower-case `dd` "day day"

```
row.Cells[2].Text = dt.ToString("MM/dd");
```

Comment: Thanks! Just the simple answer I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer really depends on if you want to support I18N/L10N. If you're interested in your date coming out something like "June 15" in en-US or "15. juni" in da-DK, you could use:

```
row.Cells[2].Text = dt.ToString("M");
```

If, on the other hand, you're interested in your date always coming out "06/15", regardless of culture, you can use:

```
row.Cells[2].Text = dt.ToString("MM/dd");
```

As far as I can tell, there's no internationalized standard date/time format for Month/Day, but you can check out the full list of standard formats for yourself at [MSDN - Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).